# text in result instead of number returns mysqli unknown column error

Tags: mysqli, error-handling

```
print_r($cfs);
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => MST Ice P [1] => MST [2] => Ice ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => MST Ice P [1] => MST [2] => Ice ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => MST 298 P [1] => MST [2] => 298 ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => MST Ice P [1] => MST [2] => Ice ) 
[4] => Array ( [0] => MST 302 P [1] => MST [2] => 302 ) 
)
```

here is my mysqli:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($cfs); $i++) 
 {
 $con->query(
 "UPDATE gages SET cfs  = {$cfs[$i][2]}, modtime = now() WHERE usgs =       
      {$stano[$i][1]}")
 or die($con->error);
}
```

Here is my error:

> Unknown column 'Ice' in 'field list'

This works fine in the summer when there in no ice.

Comment: What datatype is the `cfs` column in your scheme

Comment: varchar(10) utf8_general_ci

Comment: Probably not, otherwise the script would never have worked

Comment: Come to think about it. There is not `column 'Ice'` in this query. Are you sure you have the correct piece of code that is throwing this error

Comment: the varchar is right out of the table structure in phpMyAdmin

Comment: Then the query should have been `UPDATE gages SET cfs  = '{$cfs[$i][2]}',....` to have ever worked.

Comment: Well the single quotes fixed it. Thanks @RiggsFolly . It had worked fine since I wrote it in May '16. The array only contained numbers. Now with winter the results often contain "Ice." I suspected that it was reading it as text and tried with double quotes. I guess I should have stuck with it a bit longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If as you say the `cfs` column is VARCHAR then it should have been coded like this with `single quotes` around the value.

I dont see how it ever worked without them.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($cfs); $i++) {
     $con->query("UPDATE gages 
                    SET cfs  = '{$cfs[$i][2]}', 
                        modtime = now() 
                    WHERE usgs = {$stano[$i][1]}") 
                or die($con->error);
}
```